# How to use thread lock when reading and writing a csv file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, csv, locking

I am working on refining `dummy blockchain` code, and want to make it impossible to `read and write csv` file if it's already being used. What should do i do?

I've put `start()`, `join()`, `acquire()`, `release()` etc all the places that i could thought, but i weren't work at all. Once gotten a message that "`Permission denied`" while i opened my file, however, it still gave me the information in the file. (All the other functions are working properly.)

```
def readBlockchain(blockchainFilePath, mode = 'internal'): 

get_lock.acquire()
print("readBlockchain is called")
importedBlockchain = [] 

try:
    with open(blockchainFilePath, 'r',  newline='') as file: 
        blockReader = csv.reader(file)
        for line in blockReader:
            block = Block(line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5],line[6])

        importedBlockchain.append(block) 

    print("Pulling blockchain from csv...")
    get_lock.release()
    return importedBlockchain

except: 
    if mode == 'internal': 
        blockchain = generateGenesisBlock()             
        importedBlockchain.append(blockchain) 
        writeBlockchain(importedBlockchain) 
        get_lock.release()
        return importedBlockchain

    else:
        get_lock.release()
        return None
```

I expect it not to be read if i've opened the csv file, and to be read after i closed the file.

I'll look forward to your answers!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at mutexes, that enables you to acquire and lock a ressource, and to unlock it once your job is finished.
Link : [mutex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mutex.html)

Comment: thanks a lot:) 
I've added lock.acquire(), lock.release() and it's working as i wanted it to be!